# Using $(this) in child anonymous function

Tags: jquery, this, anonymous-function

I'm trying to use `$(this)` inside an anonymous function so that I can call two animations at the same time. Before putting the animations in the function, it worked, but after putting them inside the function `$(this)` seems to be taken out of scope...

```
$('#chat_input input').focusin(function(event){
    console.log(this); //prints correct input element

    $(function(){
        console.log(this); //prints "#document"
        $(this).transition({width: 840, duration: 200, paddingLeft: 60});
        $('.target').fadeIn();
    })

})
```

Why does `$(this)` become `#document`?

**Edit:**
To those of you reading this and saying "this has nothing to do with playing concurrent animations," you're right. The solution for that problem is to use `queue: false`

Comment: `$(function(){}` is equiv to `$(document).ready()`, hence the `#document`

Comment: Just a thought, but could the people posting the 'cache the variable' based answers re-read the question? It's basically 'why does this happen' not 'how can I get around this.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$(function(){})` is equivalent to `$(document).ready(function(){})`, which obviously gets a context of `document`.

I suggest completely removing `$(function(){` because it's almost never needed inside of an event.

```
$('#chat_input input').focusin(function(event){
    console.log(this); //prints correct input element    
    console.log(this); //prints correct input element (duh)
    $(this).transition({width: 840, duration: 200, paddingLeft: 60});
    $('.target').fadeIn();    
});
```

The only reason you would need to wait for the dom to be ready inside an event is if you are triggering said event directly before the document is ready. It's very unlikely that the user would be able to trigger the event before the DOM is ready unless your DOM is absurdly large.

Answer (score 1):

Because this:

```
$(function(){
```

is equivalent to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

Attaching a ready handler to the `document`.  Inside that handler, `this` is the `document`.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
$(function(){
    //...
});
```

is synonymous with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //...
});
```

This is different from an [anonymous function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#JavaScript) which looks something like this:

```
(function(){
    // ...
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the outer function do this...

```
var self = this;
```

Then within the child function use `self` instead of `this`

Answer (score 0):

Just cache the first this.

```
$('#chat_input input').focusin(function(event){
    console.log(this); //prints correct input element
    var $this = $(this);

    $(function(){
        console.log($this); //prints "#document"
        $this.transition({width: 840, duration: 200, paddingLeft: 60});
        $('.target').fadeIn();
    })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

That is expected with Javascript context scope. `this` refers to the context that the question was called from. Example:

```
var myfunc = function(){
    console.log(this);
};

var a = ['a'];
var b = ['b'];
var c = ['c'];

a.myfunc = myfunc; // ["a", myfunc: function]
b.myfunc = myfunc; // ["b", myfunc: function]
c.myfunc = myfunc; // ["c", myfunc: function]

a.myfunc();
b.myfunc();
c.myfunc();
```

There are a few ways around it:

Cross-browser:

```
$('#chat_input input').focusin(function(event){
    console.log(this); //prints correct input element

    var self = this;

    $(function(){
        console.log(self);
        $(self).transition({width: 840, duration: 200, paddingLeft: 60});
        $('.target').fadeIn();
    })

})
```

Cross-browser using [jQuery.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/):

```
$('#chat_input input').focusin(function(event){
    console.log(this); //prints correct input element

    $($.proxy(function(){
        console.log(this); //prints "#document"
        $(this).transition({width: 840, duration: 200, paddingLeft: 60});
        $('.target').fadeIn();
    }, this))

})
```

Modern browsers using [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
$('#chat_input input').focusin(function(event){
    console.log(this); //prints correct input element

    $((function(){
        console.log(this); //prints "#document"
        $(this).transition({width: 840, duration: 200, paddingLeft: 60});
        $('.target').fadeIn();
    }).bind(this))

})
```